# Render a component by clicking a link in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a story in storybook, but that isn't too relevant to the question at hand. Basically, I need to build a situation where I have an anchor tag that, when clicked, opens a dialog box/modal window. The dialog is a component, `<Dialog />`. I'm mocking it up as something that looks like:

```
<a onclick={launches Dialog component}>Click Me</a>
```

This seems like a simple question and I just don't know the answer. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have a few ways to achieve your needs.

1. Using `useState` and conditional rendering

```
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)
<a onClick={() => setOpen(true)}>Click Me</a>
{open && <MyComponent />}
```

2. Using `useState` and css

```
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)
<a onClick={() => setOpen(true)}>Click Me</a>
{/* You could use visibility instead of display */}
<MyComponent style={{display: open ? 'block' : 'none'}} />
```

3. In case of a new window, I'd recommend using some external library such as [react-new-window](https://github.com/rmariuzzo/react-new-window)